# Only callback if calling the same object

Tags: javascript, oop, callback

I am trying to incorporate a check **if the Callback** Function **is a Call to the same Object.**

I've made a rough Sketch for my Friend (because he isn't into JS), that he unsderstood pretty well.

```
function foo(callback){
    if(callback === foo) callback.call();
}
foo(function(){
    foo()
});
```

So I will check if the callback within the given prarmeters is the same Function (self executing?).
In the first instance i thought i could just check if the called Function is an instance of the Object. Because I'm working with Object constructors.  (`if( newfoo instanceof foo )`) But it turns out the called Function is an **IIFE** and the type of the Callback is an Function instead of an Object.

I've made up an Javascript Example that covers my Situation pretty well.

```
(function(){
    foo = function(){
        // Here are Private Functions within this Object
        return{
            bar: function(callback){
                if(typeof callback !== "undefined" && typeof callback === "function") callback(); // && if callback === object constructor
            }
        }
    }
}(this));


var Foo = new foo();
Foo.bar(function(){
    Foo.bar(function(){ // This Callbacks should be executed
        alert('Callback got called!'); // But the Callback that is no instance of 'Foo' should not be executed!
    });
})
```

I hope i have explained it good enough.
And Hopefully someone can help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: In your example both callbacks are not instances of `Foo`. The only way for callback to be an instance is this `Foo.bar(Foo.bar)` then you could compare `callback === this.bar`. However this is not what you want of course.

Comment: Have you tried with this === callback?

Comment: @dfsq @Lajos No, i've just tested it, both variations didn't work. Even when i call `Foo.bar(Foo.bar());`, is `(callback === this)` false.

Comment: Of course it will not work. `this` is an object instance which holds `bar` method. And the **only** way callback to be `this.bar` is when callback function is itself `Foo.bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve very strange problem, however it's still possible to make it work. Technically you want to invoke only those callbacks that has `Foo.bar` invocation inside anywhere. In this case you can get function sourse code with `toString()` method and simple check it with regular expression. Something like this:

```js
(function () {

    function hasOwnFunction(callback) {
        return /\.bar\(/.test(callback.toString());
    }

    this.foo = function () {
        // Here are Private Functions within this Object
        return {
            bar: function (callback) {
                if (typeof callback === "function" && hasOwnFunction(callback)) callback();
            }
        }
    }
}(this));


var Foo = new foo();
Foo.bar(function () {
    alert('I should be called 1');
    Foo.bar(function () {
        alert('I should be called 2')
        Foo.bar(function () {
            alert('Should not be called');
        })
    });
});
```

Also note that the only way for callback **to be an instance** of `Foo` is situation `Foo.bar(Foo.bar)`. only then it makes sense to compare `callback === this.bar`. However this is not what you want of course, because it will lead to infinite recursion.

Comment: You, Good Sir, have cured my headache of today! Thank You! Thank You!